# Eigenvalues and eigenspaces of reflections

Tags: geometry

Let T be the reflection about the line $6x+y=0$ in the euclidean plane. The standard matrix A of T has 2 eigenvalues. Find the two eigenvalues and their corresponding eigenspaces using geometric reasoning.

---

I'm completely lost with this problem. I don't know where to start, except for finding the standard matrix A of T (which can be found with the formula).

However, when knowing the standard matrix A of T, how can we find the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors using geometric reasoning? I can find them using the long, standard way, but is there another possible method to solve this problem? It seems straightforward.

Thank you very much for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

Eigenvectors are vectors whose direction doesn't change when the linear operation is applied.  (I count a direction change of $180^\circ$ as not a change.)  For example, think about a vector $v$ perpendicular to the line.  Then $Tv = -v$, which makes $v$ an eigenvector.  Think about another example of a vector whose direction isn't changed.

Answer (score 0):

An eigenvector is a vector that after multiplying by $A$ (or after applying $T$ which is equivalent) yields a multiple of the same vector. Geometrically, this means the result remains in the same line.

I will not be too hard to see that if you are reflecting about a line then every vector along the line will remain fixed. Fixing a vector is equivalent to the existence of an eigenvalue equal to $1$. Also, a vector perpendicular to the line will be sent to the same line but with a negative sign, which is equivalent to the existence of an eigenvalue to $-1$.

This being said. The line $6x+y=0$ can be described as $\{t(-1,6):t\in \mathbb{R}\}$ and its perpendicular line as $\{t(6,1):t\in \mathbb{R}\}$. The vectors $(-1,6)$ and $(6,1)$ are the eigenvectors of the for the eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$ respectively. Each of this lines is an eigenspace, which by definition, is the vector space generated by the vectors sharing the same eigenvalue.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the ways a reflection can take a vector $v$ to $\lambda v$ for some $\lambda$. If the vector is parallel to the reflection line, then it won't be affected by the reflection at all and $Tv = v$, cooresponding to $\lambda = 1$. The only other possibility is if the matrix $T$ takes $v$ to $-v$, corresponding to an eigenvalue of $1$. Thus the corresponding eigenspaces are $\{\alpha(6,1)\}$ and $\{\beta(-1,6)\}$ for $\alpha, \beta \in \Bbb{R}$ for eigenvalues $1,-1$ respectively.